# Error while making bottom navigation bar for android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am fairly new in android development. I tried implementing navigation bar in my app which switch
between fragments it has 4 fragments (home, search, favorites, settings) ,but I faced error related to xml which is

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.masala_food_recipes/com.example.masala_food_recipes.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28 in com.example.masala_food_recipes:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #28 in com.example.masala_food_recipes:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView" :

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/bottomNavigationBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Indicator"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/icon_color"
        app:itemPaddingBottom="16dp"
        app:itemPaddingTop="12dp"
        app:itemRippleColor="@color/light_orange"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/label_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.kt

```
package com.example.masala_food_recipes


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.data.DataManager
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.data.interactors.Cuisines
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.data.interactors.ForYouRecipe
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.data.interactors.SearchRecipe
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.data.interactors.UnderFiveIngredient
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.data.interactors.UnderTwentyMinRecipe
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.ui.fragment.FavouriteFragment
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.ui.fragment.HomeFragment
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.ui.fragment.SearchFragment
import com.example.masala_food_recipes.ui.fragment.SettingFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var homeScreen: HomeFragment
    private val favouriteScreen = FavouriteFragment()
    private lateinit var searchScreen : SearchFragment
    private val settingScreen = SettingFragment()

    private val allRecipes by lazy { DataManager(this).getAllRecipesData() }
    private val under20MinList by lazy { UnderTwentyMinRecipe(allRecipes).execute() }
    private val under5IngredientList by lazy { UnderFiveIngredient(allRecipes).execute() }
    private val cuisineList by lazy { Cuisines(allRecipes).getCuisineCards() }
    private val forYouList by lazy { ForYouRecipe(allRecipes).execute() }
    private val searchList by lazy { SearchRecipe(allRecipes).execute() }

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        if (sharedPref.getBoolean("current_state", false)) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        homeScreen = HomeFragment(cuisineList, forYouList, under20MinList, under5IngredientList)
        searchScreen = SearchFragment(searchList)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment_container_view)
        val currentFragmentId = navController.currentDestination?.id
        if (currentFragmentId == R.id.homeFragment) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ -> finish() }
                .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
            val alert = builder.create()
            alert.show()
        }
        else navController.popBackStack()

    }
}
```

error:

```
 Process: com.example.masala_food_recipes, PID: 18474
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.masala_food_recipes/com.example.masala_food_recipes.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28 in com.example.masala_food_recipes:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #28 in com.example.masala_food_recipes:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

Comment: I would remove properties in the FragmentContainerView in the xml file until I found which item is giving the error.

Comment: From the documentation I see: “ app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"” on line 28. Did you rename that?